# print last 5 values in array bash

Tags: bash

How I can print last any number of values by doing something like echo " ${ARRAY[-5:]} "; 
from
372 454 130 427 793 57 810 808 322 362 705 113 819 12 688
to 
322 362 705 113 819 12 688

```
for i in {1..14}
do
ARRAY+=($((RANDOM%886+0)))
done
echo " ${ARRAY[*]} "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax to print last 5 values from an array:

```
echo "${ARRAY[@]: -5}"
```

This will print:

```
705 113 819 12 688
```

Comment: thank you! i was trying without space and did not work. thank you again.